# Azure App Service accept all domain names

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to have an App Service respond to all domain names that it receives? I would really like to be able to deploy to an App Service plan, rather than a VM. **Note** I am not trying to do wildcard subdomains - these require adding them through the Azure console. I am trying to accept any domain name that the app service receives. Adding and verifying each domain is not practical.

I have a multitenant app, so this is really important to me so that customers can use their own domain names.

I've tried adding the domain * and *.*, but it fails validation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this because Azure requires validation of domain ownership by adding specific records to DNS. Here is a [discussion as to why they do that](https://serverfault.com/questions/718503/why-do-you-need-the-awverify-cname-record-for-azure).

The best you might be able to do is to [automate or script the binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#automate-with-scripts), but even then you would need assistance from your third party partners/customers to verify  their DNS ownership.

An alternative would be to transfer your DNS to Azure and use subdomains. I know you've said you're not looking at that solution, but using the Azure DNS offering would allow you to [fully script out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets) the onboarding process for a new customer.

Answer (score -3):

Could you ensure that the changes to your DNS settings have been confirmed and validated from your DNS provider’s end. For certain providers, such as GoDaddy, changes to DNS records don't become effective until you select a separate Save Changes link.

For more details, refer "[**Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)".

You may refer [**MSDN**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85d683cc-b5db-4808-8922-6f0abcae1e3b/hostname-not-adding?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) thread, which addresses similar issue.

Comment: Does not address the question. I am not talking about DNS validation.